# On Ubuntu 18:04: scan bluetooth devices results in: org.bluez.Error.InProgress

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth, ubuntu-18.04, bluez

I'm trying to pair a Bluetooth headset on Ubuntu 18.04 via UI using the blueman UI but it won't find new devices. When I try to manually start discovery I get an error in the status bar:

[image]

Pressing on the "more" button I get an ugly exception stack:

[image]

And no device will be discovered (I can turn them on/off, in pairing mode, reset them, etc)

I tried to reboot, restart the bluetooth service and bring my system up to date - with no success yet.

On command line everything looks fine at first:

```
$ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    **:**:**:**:**:**
```

but `hcitool scan` is not fine with me:

```
$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
Inquiry failed: Device or resource busy
```

I tried `bluetoothctl` and devices discovered earlier are listed:

```
$ bluetoothctl 
[NEW] Controller **:**:**:**:** mycomputer [default]
[NEW] Device **:**:**:**:**:** Bose Mini II SoundLink
[NEW] Device **:**:**:**:**:** LG V30
```

But when I try to start a scan here:

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
Failed to start discovery: org.bluez.Error.InProgress
[bluetooth]# scan off
Failed to stop discovery: org.bluez.Error.InProgress
```

What's going on here? Searching the internet I found a lot of questions containing "org.bluez.Error.InProgress" but this particular error hadn't been handled anywhere..

Comment: If your adapter ID is 0a12:0001 and it is a clone (non-original), you are in troubles. Check this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#CSR_Dongle_0a12:0001. I bought the same 3 days ago and I could get back. I will buy a non-clone one.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had the CSR Dongle too.

Answer (score -1):

I find a script on gist that fix's this bug on kernel. https://gist.github.com/nevack/6b36b82d715dc025163d9e9124840a07

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.